# Can I use `eval` with `rolling()`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Assuming I have a pandas dataframe and I want to create a new column which uses a rolling window e.g.:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(0,100)})
test['rol'] =  test.rolling(20,center=False).sum()
```

Is there a way to use the `eval` function to do this *inplace*?

---

Bonus: I would like to understand possible performance issues (memory and speed) between `eval`, `assign` and  `df['some_column_name'] = ...`

Comment: What do you mean by `eval`? Rolling does not support 'eval'.

Comment: I think you may have replied. For example, if I wanted to add another column called 'add2', I could use in the above example `test.eval('add2 = x+2')`.  I was wondering if there was a way to combine `eval` and `rolling`, but from what you are saying it is not supported.

Comment: I think you mean `assign`, not `eval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `assign` but this creates a copy of your dataframe:

```
df = df.assign(rol=df['x'].rolling(20).sum())
```

Or use direct assignment as you done:

```
df['rol'] = df['x'].rolling(20,center=False).sum())
```

but `eval` is not possible with [`rolling` window](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/window.html)

Performance for your sample:

```
%timeit df.assign(rol=df['x'].rolling(20,center=False).sum())
845 µs ± 67.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df['rol'] =  df['x'].rolling(20).sum()
699 µs ± 39.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For 1,000,000 of records:

```
%timeit df.assign(rol=df['x'].rolling(20,center=False).sum())
28.5 ms ± 1.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df['rol'] =  df['x'].rolling(20).sum()
36.4 ms ± 163 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**For large dataset `pd.assign` become better than direct assignment** (and I don't know why...)

Comment: For large dataset, is the later (direct assignment) preferable, in terms of memory and/or speed of computation ?

Comment: But then this is not a pipe and already what OP did in the first place, no?

Comment: @NMech. I don't know if my benchmark is bad or not but for large dataset, `pd.assign` become better than direct assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `assign` to make your pipe:

```
test = (pd.DataFrame({'x': range(0,100)})
          .assign(rol= lambda s: s.rolling(20,center=False).sum())
       )
```

output:

```
     x     rol
0    0     NaN
1    1     NaN
2    2     NaN
...
97  97  1750.0
98  98  1770.0
99  99  1790.0
```

*NB. most operation ares **NOT** done in place in pandas (in the sense that there is no copy involved), even when the operation has a `inplace` keyword. The operation is usually done on a copy and replaces the original. The confusion around this paramater is why `inplace` might be deprecated in future pandas versions*